# preg_replace php regex

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-match

Okey I got two questions.

Number one. I really suck at regex, it just can't get into my head. Any ideas how to think or learn, any good tutorials? (I've searched and i find them , for being tutorials, too advanced.)

Number two:

Lets say i got those 3 strings:

```
$string = "his";

$str1 = "hi";
$str2 = "s";
```

So what I want to do is a regex that looks for hi and replaces it. But! if there is "s" in the string it wont be replaced. Like this.

```
preg_replace('/'.$str1.'^['.$str2.']/',"replace it with this",$string);
```

It's not working! (ofcourse not, regex isn't my thing!)

As I said, I don't get this with regex. I want to find str1 and if str2 isn't in the string it wont be replaced. **Anyone?**

Comment: does string 2 always follow string 1 or can it be anywhere?

Comment: First: This is a good tutorial: http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorialcnt.html - If you have specific points where you're getting stuck, ask a specific question about that point.

Comment: I really love [RegexBuddy](http://www.regexbuddy.com/). Use it to build, explain, test and debug regular expressions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$str = 'his';

$s1 = 'hi';
$s2 = 's';

$result = preg_replace('~' . preg_quote($s1) . '(?!' . preg_quote($s2) . ')~', 'replace with this', $str);
                      // ~hi(?!s)~
                      // this regex means:
                      //   "hi" string followed by anything but "s"

var_dump($result);
```

Live examples:

1. http://ideone.com/XjX9n3
2. http://ideone.com/U2JdkL

Comment: Whatif i want to do exactly as I said but by using arrays? preg_replace ($arr.(?! $arr2,$replacewitharray ,$instring) (just fast example)

Comment: @Kilise: what do you want to achieve? Regular expression is **always a string**. Your question looks like "what I want to do the same but by using orange"

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to make multiple filters, like: `s`,`m` etc or more..

```
$s = array('s', 'm');
$result = preg_replace('~hi(?!'. join('|', $s) .')~', 'replace with this', 'him');
print $result; // him
// and
$result = preg_replace('~hi(?!'. join('|', $s) .')~', 'replace with this', 'hiz');
print $result; // replace with thisz
```